# Disable auto rotation for special method in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autorotate

Is there a way to stop auto rotation in swift for specific method?

Want to stop auto rotation when executing method of ViewController..

Comment: Please improve your question!! Provide code snippet or be clear in your intent.

Comment: I set `func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool` to true for my ViewController and now I want to stop the auto rotation when I'm in a certain method

Answer (score 2):

Make one `Bool` instance and return its value in the `shouldAutorotate` method of your `ViewController`.

```
var allowRotate: Bool = true

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return allowRotate
}
```

Now set the `allowRotate` to `false` inside your method where you want to stop the rotation after that set it to `true` to allow it again.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these methods in UIViewController:

```
func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool
func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to subclass 'UINavigationController', implement shouldAutorotate and use your navigation controller class in your storyboard.

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    let currentViewController = self.topViewController

    if test.isKindOfClass(NewviewController.self) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: I want to rotate my VC but when I'm in a certain method in the VC, the autorotation should stop

Comment: Then you can use the above function in the particular VC.

Answer (score 0):

Use these methods in ViewController of each view that needs to be portrait:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```